Unable to install pandasai
I am facing issues with installing PandasAI in Visual Studio Code.
The command used - pip install pandas
I have upgraded my Python version to 3.12.3 and still, it is not installing. Upgraded pip, and did pip install pandas again (to check if it was because of a version issue), but nothing worked. Please help!

Upgraded Python, pip, and installed Python again.

The message tells you what to do, did you try it?

i installed Microsoft C++ Build Tool and installed pandas again. Did not work..

This work in me pip install --only-binary :all: pandasai

I've got the same error message.
The solution I found is to install pandas with a lower version.
If you install pandas==1.5.3, then you may be able to install pandasai.
In my case, I could not downgrade pandas in Anaconda Environment. So I created another v-env without Anaconda, and installed pandasai. If you just type in "pip install pandasai", it will automatically install pandas==1.5.3.
